# Computing injective hulls over a lower triangular matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be the ring $\begin{pmatrix} {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & 0 \\ {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & {\mathbb Z }_{ p } \end{pmatrix}$ with $p$ prime. $R$ is an artinian ring and is also a $\mathbb Z_p$-$\mathbb Z_p$ bimodule in an obvious way.

The lattice of ideals of $R$ is (where arrows go from bigger to smaller submodules):

$$ \begin{array}{ccccc}
 R & \rightarrow & Soc(R)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & {\mathbb Z }_{ p } \end{pmatrix} & \rightarrow & I=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ { 0 } & {\mathbb Z }_{ p } \end{pmatrix}\\
 \downarrow & &  \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
 \begin{pmatrix} {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & 0 \\ {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & { 0 } \end{pmatrix} & \rightarrow & Rad(R)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & { 0 } \end{pmatrix}={ S }_{ 1 } & \rightarrow & 0
\end{array} $$

We have that R-simp={${ S }_{ 1 }=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & { 0 } \end{pmatrix}, { S }_{ 2 }=R/\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & {\mathbb Z }_{ p } \end{pmatrix}$} and that $I$ is isomorphic to $S_1$.

The question is: why is $E(S_1)=\begin{pmatrix} {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & 0 \\ {\mathbb Z }_{ p } & { 0 } \end{pmatrix}$ ($E(S_1)$ denotes the injective hull of $S_1$ in $R$-mod) and why is $S_2$ already injective?

It is important to say that I really do not want to use Baer´s test.

I noticed that R/Rad is isomorphic to the direct sum of $S_1$ and $S_2$, so I thought that computing the injective hull of $R/Rad(R)$ and decomposing it as the direct sum of the injective hulls I look for then I could finish via Krull-schmidt (I've already checked the hypothesis required).

Lam's book says that if we have a finite dimensional k-algebra R, then the injective hull of $R/Rad(R)$ in $R$-Mod is ${ Hom }_{ k }(R,k)$ viewed as $R$-module, so all is reduced to compute ${ Hom }_{ \mathbb{Z}_p }(R,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ **as $R$-module** but I couldn't see how.

Does anyone knows how to compute it or something that could help?

Other ways or hints are welcome.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of reformatting the lattice of ideals of $R$; feel free to revert if you preferred the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout, I assume you are looking at *left* $R$-modules.

Since $R$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module, then using the duality
$$ D={\rm Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(-, \mathbb{Z}_p): {\rm mod}\ R^{op} \to {\rm mod}\ R, $$
where $R^{op}$ is the opposite algebra, is a good way to answer your question.  More precisely, projective $R^{op}$-modules will be sent to injective $R$-modules by this functor $D$.

The rest of the post is simply a detailed computation of the images of the projective $R^{op}$-modules by $D$.

It is not hard to see that $R^{op}$ is isomorphic to the ring $\pmatrix{\mathbb{Z}_p & \mathbb{Z}_p \\ 0 & \mathbb{Z}_p}$, which decomposes as the direct sum of the two projectives $Q_1=\pmatrix{\mathbb{Z}_p & 0 \\ 0 & 0}$ and $Q_2=\pmatrix{0 & \mathbb{Z}_p \\ 0 & \mathbb{Z}_p}$.  We need to compute the image of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ by the duality functor $D$.

Clearly, $DQ_1$ is simple, since it is one-dimensional.  To know whether it is isomorphic to $S_1$ or $S_2$, multiply by idempotent elements of $R$: if $f\in DQ_1$ and $\pmatrix{x & 0\\ 0 & 0}\in Q_1$, then
$$ (\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}\cdot f)(\pmatrix{x & 0\\ 0 & 0}) = f(\pmatrix{x & 0\\ 0 & 0}\pmatrix{1 & 0\\ 0 & 0})=f(\pmatrix{x & 0\\ 0 & 0}) $$
and
$$ (\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}\cdot f)(\pmatrix{x & 0\\ 0 & 0}) = f(\pmatrix{x & 0\\ 0 & 0}\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 0 & 1})=f(\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 0 & 0}) = 0, $$
so $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}\cdot f = f$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}\cdot f = 0$.  This means that the action of $R$ on $DQ_1$ is the same as that on the module called $S_2$ in your post.  Thus $DQ_1$ is isomorphic to $S_2$.

We now have to compute $DQ_2$.  Note that, since $Q_2$ is the projective cover of the simple module $S=R^{op}/rad(R^{op})$, we get that $DQ_2$ is the injective hull of $DS$, which is isomorphic to $S_1$.  All that remains is to show that $DQ_2$ is isomorphic to $\pmatrix{\mathbb{Z}_p & 0 \\ \mathbb{Z}_p & 0}$.  An explicit isomorphism is not hard to find.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I know this thing about duality.

Comment: I solved it using lemma 3.42, page 77 of Lam's book.